# Bulk Insert how to skip column using format file in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a scenario were in a table has 5 columns, but data (CSV) file has only 2 columns of data. Because the 1st column is an Identity column, 4th & 5th have default constraints. So these columns don't need value from CSV. Please note CSV will always have all values (rows and columns in double quotes)

I tried to skip the 1st column by referring to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-skip-a-table-column-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 but seems I am missing something, because on executing bulk insert command I get an

> Cannot bulk load CSV file. Invalid terminator is specified for source column number 2 in the format file "C:\MyData\Demo1_Format.fmt". All source column terminators must be the same except the last one when CSV format is specified. Only row terminator should be different

My code:

```
CREATE table dbo.test1
(
    [UniqueID] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Id] CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsDelete] [TINYINT] NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [Rootpid] VARCHAR(25) NULL 
         CONSTRAINT defVal_RootPid_TEST1 DEFAULT '20190110035929_x9zh5'
);
```

Demo1_Format.fmt

```
14.0
3
1 SQLCHAR 0 0 "\"" 0 "" ""
2 SQLCHAR 0 9999 "\",\"" 2 Id ""
3 SQLCHAR 0 9999 "\"\r\n" 3 Name ""
```

Demo1.csv

```
"Id","Name"
"1","James"
"2","Scott"
```

T-SQL:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.test1 from 'C:\MyData\Demo1.csv'
WITH 
    (FORMAT = 'CSV', 
     FIRSTROW = 2, 
     FORMATFILE = 'C:\MyData\Demo1_Format.fmt')
```

**Update** when I remove Format = 'CSV' parameter and keep format file as it is then it works. But I need the format parameter because it has several benefits like handling double quotes, line break, special characters issues within data. So can't I use both, format file to skip columns and format='CSV' parameters for handling data issues?

Comment: You mean in format file right? It still gives the same error. Even if value is 0 / 1

Comment: Sorry I realised that as soon as I typed that.

Comment: Perhaps give that row the same column terminator? Even if ignored.

Comment: This is what I Kept now  1 SQLCHAR 0 0   "\",\""  0  ""         " "   now error is Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Try use the hexadecimal ASCII value for double quote? So `"0x22,0x22"` or `"0x220x2C0x22"`.

Comment: Still same error.

Comment: Avoid format files if possible. They are a pain. Create a view of your table that only contains the two columns of interest and load into that view.

Comment: In my case its reverse I can use a format file, but don't want to create an additional view. One Update when I remove Format = 'CSV' parameter and keep format file as it is then it works. But I need the format parameter because it has several benefits like handling double quotes, line break, special characters issues within data. So can't I use both, format file to skip columns and format='CSV' parameters for handling data issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this format file:  I think the new Format=CSV option does some thinking that the Format File no longer needs to do...

```
14.0
2
1       SQLCHAR             0       1       ","      2     Id           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       50      "\r\n"   3     Name         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```